# How do I get rid of chart in all workbooks in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried running this code to delete any charts before allowing the code to run but error of "Object doesn't support this method" keeps coming up.

```
Dim wksht As Worksheets

Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

For Each wksht In Source_Workbook

   If ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then

      ChartObjects.Delete

   End If 

Next wksht
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the corrected code:

```
Sub DeleteAllChartObjects()
  Dim wksht As Worksheet
  For Each wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wksht.ChartObjects.count > 0 Then wksht.ChartObjects.Delete
  Next wksht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate each chart and delete it individually.  You're trying to delete the collection.